# Blockcypher transaction signing error using bitcoinjs

Tags: javascript, blockchain, bitcoin, blockcypher

Im trying to sign a Bitcoin testnet transaction using blockcypher and the bitcoinjs lib described [here](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#creating-transactions), but I have run into this error and I am not usre what I am doing wrong.

```
{"error": "Couldn't deserialize request: invalid character 'x' in literal true (expecting 'r')"}
```

When searching around I cannot find a solution to the problem, I have contacted blockcypher but they never respond. Here is the code im using to sign the transaction, does anyone know why its giving me this error?

```
var bitcoin = require("bitcoinjs-lib");
var buffer  = require('buffer');
var keys    = new bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF('cMvPQZiG5mLARSjxbBwMxKwzhTHaxgpTsXB6ymx7SGAeYUqF8HAT', bitcoin.networks.testnet);

var newtx = {
  inputs: [{addresses: ['ms9ySK54aEC2ykDviet9jo4GZE6GxEZMzf']}],
  outputs: [{addresses: ['msWccFYm5PPCn6TNPbNEnprA4hydPGadBN'], value: 1000}]
};
// calling the new endpoint, same as above
$.post('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/txs/new', JSON.stringify(newtx))
  .then(function(tmptx) {
    // signing each of the hex-encoded string required to finalize the transaction
    tmptx.pubkeys = [];
    tmptx.signatures = tmptx.tosign.map(function(tosign, n) {
      tmptx.pubkeys.push(keys.publicKey.toString("hex"));

const SIGHASH_ALL = 0x01;
return bitcoin.script.signature.encode(keys.sign(new buffer.Buffer(tosign, "hex")), SIGHASH_ALL,).toString("hex");

    });
    // sending back the transaction with all the signatures to broadcast
    $.post('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/txs/send', tmptx).then(function(finaltx) {
      console.log(finaltx);
    }).catch(function (response) {
   console.log(response.responseText);
});
  }).catch(function (response) {
   console.log(response.responseText);
});
```

Comment: Did you solve this eventually?

Comment: Why not just use the BitcoinJS library to fully build the transaction and only use blockcypher to broadcast the signed tx. You could follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@aniketdivekar/bitcoin-create-sign-and-push-transaction-2ea877c08ab4 and then use https://sochain.com/api#get-unspent-tx to get the UTXO's